# Zabbix disk space monitoring using active agent in linux server

Tags: network-monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

Zabbix server is giving same value for all linux servers upon disk space monitoring using Zabbix Active Agents. I am using Zabbix server 3.2. Please help.

Comment: Please go to Monitoring -> Latest Data -> Name like "Free disk space" -> Filter ->  tell us the key names, intervals, type, last check, last value. Just edit your question.

Comment: Hi @kubanczyk, Here is what I have: Name: File Systems: Free disk space on / (percentage), Last Check: 2018-03-23 19:49:36.  Last Value: 51.8%. All values are same in all hosts. I was supposed to receive different values.

Comment: The key names are like `vfs.fs.blabla` please tell those. And. Please. Edit. All. Of. It. Into. Your. Question.

Comment: Hi @kubanczyk , Here is the detail information I have:         Parent items: 
Template OS Linux Active ⇒ Template App Zabbix Agent Active,   
      Name: Free disk space on $1 (percentage),         Type: Zabbix agent, 
        Key: vfs.fs.size[{#FSNAME},pfree],         Host interface: 0.0.0.0:10050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your agents are misconfigured - check the agent configuration file, parameter `Hostname`. This is the host which will get the value. The value of this configuration parameter must match the host name - not IP, not DNS. In this case, it sounds as if you have one or more agents sending data with various `Hostname` values.

Looks like it was template that was misconfigured - the item was passive, not active.

Comment: Hi @Richlv, Thanks for your quick response. Hostname in all server seems correct and agents are sending correct data for memory and swap space but not the correct disk storage space value. I could not understand what else could go wrong. I have double, triple checked hostnames on zabbix agents and server.

Comment: Hmm, in that case please add info on what values you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi @Richlv, Here is what I have: Name: File Systems: Free disk space on / (percentage), Last Check: 2018-03-23 19:49:36.  Last Value: 51.8%. All values are same in all hosts. I was supposed to receive different values.

Comment: What's the item type for that item? Is it "Zabbix agent" by any chance, and is it maybe reporting diskspace on the Zabbix server?

Comment: Hi @Richlv , It is actually "Zabbix agent" on item type.

Comment: Your configuration is broken. "Zabbix agent" is the passive type. Most likely it is querying the same IP address/DNS name, as set in your hosts in the interface. If you really want to use active items, change it to "Zabbix agent (active)" in the template.

Comment: Hi @Richlv, That works. Thank you so much for your help.